# extends function from blade doesn't work

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem, I don't know why but when I extend a blade template then I call it,  it prints an empty page in my browser.

In my /app/views/layout.blade.php

```
<div>
    @yield('main')
</div>
```

In my /app/views/error/notfound.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('main')
<myhtmlcode>
</myhtmlcode>
@stop
```

My notfound template is called when I catch a NotFoundHttpException

```
App::error(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $exception, $code)
{
    return View::make('error.notfound');
});
```

Every other View::make work fine.. this one worked fine before.. but I certainly made an invisible mistake. I need your hindsight guys.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have a corresponding `@stop` for each `@section` statement.

Comment: Yes of course I had a @stop at the end of my error.notfound template sorry I forgot but I edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm obvious..

So I prefix all my routes

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{lang}', 'before' => 'set.lang'), function($lang) {
});
```

So I tried to call my template notfound.blade.php inside my route::group with a route test and it didn't work too..
But there was a php warning telling me that he can't found the $lang variable in my layout.blade.php !

So I guess that when I returned my view by catching the notFoundHtppException there was this error too but laravel didn't show me anything.. so I just had to inject the $lang variable in my View::make like this in app/start/global.php

```
App::error(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $exception, $code)
{
    return View::make('error.notfound', ['lang' => App::getLocale()]);
});
```

Now it works like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting `@stop` in your `notfound.blade.php`

> /app/views/layout.blade.php

```
<div>
    @yield('main')
</div>
```

> /app/views/error/notfound.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('main')
<myhtmlcode></myhtmlcode>
@stop
```

[refer to this](http://laravel.com/docs/templates)

Comment: Not your fault, I just forgot to notice it, but I edited my post while your were writting this anwser.
So doesn't work even with the @stop at the end.

Comment: atleast you made it more interesting.

Comment: In your App::error callback just return some string like "Not Found" or whatever you like just to test even if it is being called or not.